# Inductive vs projective limit of sequence of split surjections

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, tag-removed

Let
$$
A_1\twoheadrightarrow
A_2\twoheadrightarrow
A_3\twoheadrightarrow
A_4\twoheadrightarrow
\cdots
$$
be an inductive sequence of **countable** abelian groups, the connecting homomorphisms of which are surjective and **split**, that is, we have embeddings $A_{n+1}\rightarrowtail A_n$ such that the composition $A_{n+1}\rightarrowtail A_n\twoheadrightarrow  A_{n+1}$ is the identity for every $n$. This means that $A_{n+1}$ is a direct summand of $A_n$.

Let $\varinjlim A_n$ denote the inductive limit of the system
$$
A_1\twoheadrightarrow
A_2\twoheadrightarrow
A_3\twoheadrightarrow
A_4\twoheadrightarrow
\cdots
$$
and let $\varprojlim A_n$ denote the projective limit of the system
$$
A_1\leftarrowtail
A_2\leftarrowtail
A_3\leftarrowtail
A_4\leftarrowtail
\cdots.
$$
We get an induced map
$$
\varprojlim A_n\to\varinjlim A_n.
$$
As [Zhen Lin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5191/zhen-lin) has shown in [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/254702/367), this map need not be surjective. Here is a weaker question:

**Question:**
If we have $\varinjlim A_n=0$, then can we conclude that $\varprojlim A_n=0$?

This would, of course, follow if the map $\varprojlim A_n\to\varinjlim A_n$ was always injective. Is there any reason to expect this?

[Earlier versions of this question were posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254649) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254822) on MSE.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's true that $\varprojlim A_n\to\varinjlim A_n$ is always injective.

We may as well assume that

$A_1\leftarrowtail
A_2\leftarrowtail
A_3\leftarrowtail
A_4\leftarrowtail
\cdots$

is a sequence of inclusions of nested subgroups, so $\varprojlim A_n$ is just the intersection. An element of the kernel of $\varprojlim A_n\to\varinjlim A_n$ is just an element $a$ of $\bigcap A_n$ that is in the kernel of the map $A_1\twoheadrightarrow A_k$ for some $k$. But this implies $a=0$ since this map is a splitting of the inclusion $A_k\rightarrowtail A_1$.

This doesn't use countability.